# Integral Test: Anticipating That Integral is Lesser Than Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

I am given the following $f(x)$ value:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+x}$

The question says that it is possible to "anticipate" that the integral of $f(x)$ would be less than the sum of the series of $f(x)$. How is it possible to determine that? Do we use a mode of comparison with a function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, that has its integral value less than the sum of its series?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is decreasing, then the riemann sum, which can be viewed as "sum of rectangles", will be larger than the series sum

Comment: Though isn't it only if we were to apply a left-hand Riemann sum on a decreasing function? If we use a right-hand Riemann sum, then the sum will be lesser than the integral value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can interpret the series sum as left riemann sum from 0 to infinity as step size  1 for monotonically decreasing function so with a simple drawing you can reach a conclusion.

Comment: I am sure you didn't intend to, but this is exactly what I wrote in the comments, and it's not clear whether you just looked at my comment and wrote this answer... Anyways whatever

Comment: @GarethMa  apparently I upload the answer late but it was because of the internet connection I didn't saw your comment but I don't want any gain from my answer thanks for kindly warning

Comment: It is fine, just keep the answer, it's concise and clear.

Comment: @GarethMa Thanks :)

Comment: Your infinite sum start from 0 and for each step I mean 1 increase in dummy variable n graphically corresponds to left Riemann sum. For visual demonstration https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRToR8HBV6qPewaUc0SnfMGD0Bj6VO0ln6-UBAs-WVlGqLn5lWf&usqp=CAU could be helpful.

Comment: @Butane If in the sigma notation we have $n=1$ as the starting value, shouldn't we use right-hand Riemann sum? The comparison is between an integral that starts from 1 to infinity and the sum with $n=1$ to infinity.

Comment: @geo_freak no again from the left consider it as you are calculating the area under the columns that their height determined by the left value of the function for each step.

Comment: Even you can consider it as moving your origin one step ahead because summation's start one step size later.

Comment: But I don't understand how we know to use Left Hand sum but not Right Hand Riemann sum in this case

Comment: left sum use rectangles whose  left top vertices are on the function and right sum uses rectangles with right top vertices are on the curve. So, for summation of the areas of the rectangles we use the function that passes through the left top vertices of the rectangles.